# Sending string via POST - unsupported media type or null parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

My controller cannot accept string via `POST` method. What could be wrong? When I create `HttpClient` and send content like this :

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new []
{
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("signature", "someexamplecontent"), 
});

var response = await _client.PostAsync(path, content);
```

I'm getting an error: `415, Unsupported media type` and it not stepping into controller. Instead, when I use `PostAsJsonAsync` - stepping into but parameter `signature` is null.

```
var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, content);
```

That's a method in a controller:

```
[HttpPost("generatecert")]
public byte[] PostGenerateCertificate([FromBody] string signature)
{      
}
```

Comment: have you checked that the request is sending the correct `Content-Type` and 
`Content-Encoding` headers, and also made sure that the server accepts the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type? Is this the only action where you are receiving POST'ed data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint is most likely configured for JSON content. If using `PostAsJsonAsync` then just pass the string to be posted.

```
var signature = "someexamplecontent";    
var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, signature);
```

the method will serialize and set the necessary content type headers for the request.

if posting a more complex object, like

```
public class Model {
    public string signature { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

The same applies, but the action would need to be updated to expect the complex object

```
[HttpPost("generatecert")]
public byte[] PostGenerateCertificate([FromBody] Model signature) {
    //... 
}
```

and the client would send the object

```
var model = new Model {
    signature = "someexamplecontent",
    id = 5
};
var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, model);
```

Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)